# Travis-CI fails with unclear error in logs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, travis-ci

Is there a way to understand what is wrong with my build, it just fails without any explanation:

[image]

I'm trying to test angularJs application with grunt test, everthing is working fine on local laptop but fails with no reason in Travis-CI

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on OSX check your folder names. OSX filesystem is case insensitive by default. Filesystem used by Travis-CI is not.